# How do I access the XML element text using xml2js other than using underscore key?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xml-parsing

I have a piece of XML looking like this:

```
<errorMessage>
    <payload encoding="plain">The error message</payload>
</errorMessage>
```

and I use xml2js parser:

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser({
    explicitCharKey: false,
    trim: true,
    explicitRoot: true,
    mergeAttrs: true
});
parser.parseString(myString, function(err, result) {
    var payload = result.errorMessage.payload;
    // how do I access the error message text?
    var errorMessage = payload[0]['_'];
});
```

I need to access `The error message` string inside `payload` element. If I use `_` key on the node containing the `<payload>` then the text is properly retrieved but using an underscore magic key for this looks suspicious.

Is this the recommended way? Are there any cleaner ways?

Answer (score 1):

The [xml2js options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js#options) documentation says this:

> ```
> attrkey (default: $): Prefix that is used to access the attributes.
> charkey (default: _): Prefix that is used to access the character content.
> ```

So it looks like `element._` is how you access the text content of `element`.  If you want to name this key something other than `_` (say, `textContent`), you can change it like this:

```
parseString(xml,  {charkey: 'textContent'}, function(err, result) {
   // result.element.textContent will hold the text value of result.element
});
```

However, I have not found a way to make the text content *always* available from the `_` key.  For example, this:

```
xml2js.parseString(
    '<element>1.23</element>', // <-- notice that this has no attributes
    function(err, result) {      
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
);
```

outputs this:

`{"element":"1.23"}`

But if you change the XML to add an attribute, like `<element attr="value">1.23</element>`, you get this:

`{"element":{"_":"1.23","$":{"attr":"value"}}}`

I need to parse XML output which sometimes has attributes but sometimes does not.  There may be a better way, but when I need the text from an element, I just call `getText(element)`, where getText is:

```
var getText = function(elt) {
    if (typeof(elt) === 'string') return elt;
    if (typeof(elt) === 'object' && elt.hasOwnProperty('_')) return elt._;
    return ''; // or whatever makes sense for your case
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you parse an XML doc with attributes, you'll get that funny underscore in your JSON results. It is what it is. If you really hate that and don't want any of the attributes in your doc, set the `ignoreAttrs : true` in your options block. Then you'll access the element text right from the element's property.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')

;(async function() {
    const xml = `
        <errorMessage>
            <payload encoding="plain">The error message</payload>
        </errorMessage>
    `
    const { errorMessage } = await transform(xml, {
        errorMessage: 'errorMessage/payload'
    })

    console.log(errorMessage)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just set `mergeAttrs` to `true` to get rid of all the `$` attribute keys:

> mergeAttrs (default: false): Merge attributes and child elements as properties of the parent, instead of keying attributes off a child attribute object. This option is ignored if ignoreAttrs is true.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js#options